# How to wrap a text using pylatex?

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

I am trying to create a table using pylatex, but I can't make it so text is being wrapped. Without wrapping, my table goes outside of the .pdf file which I am generating.

Following code generates a table:

```
with doc.create(Section('Items')):
        with doc.create(Table(position='h!')) as table:
            with doc.create(Tabular('|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|')) as tabular:
                tabular.add_hline()
                tabular.add_row(("dasddasdas", "sdsdsdsdfjsdn nnnsdskjfsdfsdf", "sdnsdsdffnnsda sdiasnhasdfnsdn", "234u234uijed", "asdasdasd", "dsadas", "dasjasdjnkasd"))
                tabular.add_hline()
                tabular.add_row(("","","","","","",""))
                tabular.add_hline()
```

And the result is
[image]

I have tried looking in documentation for text wrapping function or argument, but I could not find anything related to it.

Comment: Try with fixed with columns, e.g. `p{2cm}`, instead of `c` columns (however it will depend on the exact text if latex can hyphenate the words, your example words might not work)

Comment: That being said: don't use vertical lines, they make your table look amateurish

Comment: (you can read up on some suggestions of how to format good looking tables at https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0 )